# How to get associated event name from observer

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer

Say I have an observer, and I want to get the name of the event that's associated with it. What's the proper way to get this string, if it's possible?

e.g. `customer_save_after` or `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the name of the triggered event you can use the following code

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
   function myObserver(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
      $event = $observer->getEvent();
      var_dump($event->getName());
   }
}
```

to see what other data is in the Event object just call getData which will display all the stored data.

```
[...]
var_dump($event->getData());
[...]
```

Comment: I tried this with the event checkout_cart_product_add_after and both the $observer->getEventName() and $event->getEventName() returned null

Comment: Please update the question with your code so we can take a look

Comment: it was not my question ;) but i simply did a var_dump on the event object, which had information but just not the event name. I wonder if this only works for some events as the one I checked with is called via `Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));`

Comment: -.- ok in my defence, it's quite early here... Thanks for the feedback, let me check into this!

Comment: @DavidManners sorry, you were right. it was `getName` on the `$event` object. Updated my question

Comment: great stuff, I wonder why the getEventName returns null

Comment: From what I see in the Varien_Event_Observer class it shouldn't. oh well, we'll just file this under one of those wonderfull mysteries that make Magento so exciting to work with I guess ;)